# How to filter by all FK coincidence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, with this structure:

Table: Matches

```
MatchId | MatchResult
```

Table: Player_Matches

```
MatchId | PlayerId
```

And data currently looks like this:

Matches:

```
MatchId | MatchResult
1       | 4-2
2       | 2-1
3       | 3-1
```

Player_Matches:

```
MatchId | PlayerId
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 1
4       | 2
4       | 3
```

The idea is that every match can have between 1 and 5 players.

How can I create a select statement recieving 1 to 5 parameters, and only get the id of those matches played by all the players passed as parameters?

For example these would be the expected output for these values:

input1 = 1 results would be:

```
1
2
3
```

input1 = 1 and input2=2 results would be:

```
1
2
```

input1= 1 and input2= 3 results would be:

```
1
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MatchId
FROM Player_Matches
WHERE PlayerId IN (1, 2, 3)           -- players 1, 2, 3
GROUP BY MatchId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PlayerId) = 3;
```

The above query would only return the first match.  It should be clear how to modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly tricky but can be broken down with the help of a `cte` to simplify matters.

Given a list of 5 parameters, any or all of which can have a specified `PlayerId`

Using a set of these PlayerIds built from `values` of the parameters, get a list of matches played by all the passed `Id` values and a count of matches played by each `Id`

Then filter this list where each player's `Matchcount` is the count of how many unique matches exist for the player in the list.

```
declare @p1 tinyint,@p2 tinyint,@p3 tinyint,@p4 tinyint,@p5 tinyint
select @p1=1;
      
with l as (
  select MatchId, PlayerId, Count(*) over(partition by matchid) MatchCount
  from t
  where exists(
    select * from (values (@p1),(@p2),(@p3),(@p4),(@p5))x(id) where x.id=t.playerid
  )
);

select l.MatchId
from l 
where MatchCount=(select Count(distinct playerid) from l)
group by l.Matchid;
```

See [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f99970c96b107ac1e06dddaef090f33) for examples.

Comment: I've been trying to understand this solution for over a day but I just couldn't. However, it works perfectly, so thanks!